# Importing contacts from other phone to Moto G

Tags: contacts, import, motorola-moto-g

I want to export my contacts from Micromax Q7 to Moto G. I have moved all the contacts to sim and then imported the contacts to Moto G from that sim. The problem is that each contact have more than one number but Moto G is showing only 1 number.

How can I get those other numbers linked with the contacts?

Answer (score 1):

SIM cards only support one number for each contact, so you should be better off exporting the contacts on your Micromax device as Contacts.vcf (export to SD card / something like that) and opening the VCF on your Moto G to commence import.

Answer (score 0):

move them in another way 
for example you can sync your contacts with your gmail account 
and when you add your gmail account to the moto g the contacts will be automatically trasfered 
this is the best way 
you can also try wondershare mobileTrans

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using [Motorola Migrate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motorola.migrate)

The description says:

> Move stuff from your old phone to your new Motorola smartphone.

Comment: I see nothing wrong to suggest apps but do mention the hyperlink such as [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motorola.migrate&hl=en). Also mention the context (copy-paste of About section of App will do) for why this app suits the question exactly. A completely unknown reader won't be able to guess or might possibly find it always.

Comment: I helped to add some basic info from the Play Store, but you have to elaborate more how it's suitable for OP, and also explain how to use it.